# Why my reducer is not changing synchronous?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a reducer that seems me async by default. I had read in alot o places that the dispatch is synchronous by default, but in this case the console.log always print an empty array in the first call of my function, and in the second call it prints with one element instead of two. I don't know if I'm doing any mistake.

```
const answerQuestion = (correctAnswer, answerText) => {
  const {
    interview: { questionGroups, responses },
  } = state;

  dispatch({
    type: ANSWER_CURRENT_QUESTION,
    payload: {
      correctAnswer,
      answerText,
    },
  });

  console.log(responses);
};
```

And I have this reducer

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ANSWER_CURRENT_QUESTION:
    return {
      ...state,
      interview: {
        ...state.interview,
        responses: [...state.interview.responses, action.payload],
      },
    };
  default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I think you not understand how redux works, so you dispatch an action sync but dispatch not wait for the result so your still running. the second time you call your function the store got new data but that not mean after dispatch the action you will the new state instanly. useSelector hook re-render the component is there is a change in the store.

Comment: I understood your explanation. I think so I was using it as a sync function. I changed the logic to change all the state in the same dispatch call and everything works now. Thanks for the clarification.